# PNG image is not created with imagepng even inside a 0777 directory

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu

From an `Android` app I post a `photo` into a `webserver`. Inside the `PHP` script I want to save the file inside a `directory` :

```
$name = "parcelle_" . $photo->lireBienPhotoSeq() . ".png";
if ( ! file_exists (RP_PHOTO_PARCELLE) ) {
    mkdir(RP_PHOTO_PARCELLE, 0777, true);
    chmod(RP_PHOTO_PARCELLE, 0777);
}
$dest = DIR_MAIN . '/data/photo_parcelle/' . $name;
$image = base64_decode($_POST["image"]);
$img = imagecreatefromstring($image);
if ($img !== false)
    imagepng($img, $dest);
$chemin = PHOTO_PARCELLE . $name;
```

The problem is that the `image` is not created and the `Android` app receives a response code 500 ( HTTP_INTERNAL_ERROR ) ! I made a `ls -l` to see the rights of the `directory` and it is 0777. So what is wrong ?

Comment: If the client gets a 500 error, you will need to check the web server's error log for more details. As long as PHP has sane error reporting settings, the error will be spelled out there. I recommend troubleshooting this code from a regular web browser instead of a handheld device, and in testing enable display errors so you can see it fail.  At the top `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` always in development, remove in production.

Comment: You have 2 (or more) options: Watch the error log as suggested, or mock up a simple HTML form which posts to the same PHP endpoint with a file input to submit a png image.  One of the best things about HTTP is that the server doesn't have know what type of client is connected.

Comment: you should avoid using 0777 (rwx for owner/group/all) for directory permissions, but rather 0755 (u:rwx, g:rw, o:rw) or even better at 0750 (u:rwx, g:rw, o:-), the `chmod` is completely unnecessary as well as when you make the directory the permissions were already set.

Comment: Also, files won't be present in the `$_POST` variable... they're handled in the [`$_FILES`](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php) variable. Easiest option it to look at that to get the temp location and move it where you need, or read its contents.

Comment: @KevinNagurski Looks like it is expecting to receive a base64 encoded string through regular POST rather than a multipart body and `$_FILES`.

Comment: `$img = imagecreatefromstring($image);` this line right here is most likely the source of the problem, whereas the image data itself is actually invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at the log then the `imagecreatefromstring` function is unknown , so the gd package is installed and it works ! The server is new and not as my local computer ! lol

Answer (score 0):

There are several things that could be going wrong on this one, and your description is not detailed enough.

How is the image POSTed ?

Are you sure it is sent as a POST variable and not as an uploaded file in $_FILES ?

Are you sure that $_POST['image'] contains the contents of a recognizable image format (JPEG, PNG, GIF, WBMP, and GD2) and not something like raw data ?

Are you sure that RP_PHOTO_PARCELLE is the same as DIR_MAIN . '/data/photo_parcelle/' ?

What is the result of imagecreatefromstring($image); ?

If you directly invoke the script do you get it to execute or a 500 error ?